# PHP pass variable to foreach loop from a mySQL result

Tags: php, mysql, loops

I need to pass a variable to a foreach loop from a mySQL result.

So I have this code:

```
    $GetClaim = "SELECT * FROM cR_Claimants WHERE memberID = '".$memberID."' AND ParentSubmission ='".$refNumb."'";
    $resultGetClaim=mysql_query($GetClaim) or die("Error select claimants: ".mysql_error());
    while($rowGetClaim = mysql_fetch_array($resultGetClaim)) {
    $name = $rowGetClaim['Name'];
$city = $rowGetClaim['city'];
$region = $rowGetClaim['region'];

    }
```

Now I need to pass the variable to the foreach

```
    foreach($name as $k=>$v) {
    echo $city;
echo $region;
etc..
    }
```

The above code does not work. I think I cannot pass a variable from a mySQL loop. The problem is also tat every row I get from the database should be related to the specific $name. So obvioiusly one $name will have its own $city etc..

How do I achieve this?

Please help

Comment: $name is just a variable . not an array is it?

Comment: What's the problem with the first code block? Looks like you already get the names.

Comment: The foreach is not working as it should. And yes $name is an array. There are more $name that will get from the database result..This is why I need a foreach $name.

Comment: `$name` cannot be an array in the code you show... its the value of the `Name` column (ell unless you are somheow unserializing it, but if thats the case you have completely ommited that code)

Comment: @prodigitalson this is why I am asking this question...because I need to know how?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either out put directly fromt eh loop or build an array and then loop through it.

```
while($rowGetClaim = mysql_fetch_array($resultGetClaim)) {
  echo $rowGetClaim['Name'];
  echo $rowGetClaim['city'];
  echo $rowGetClaim['region'];

}
```

OR

```
while($rowGetClaim = mysql_fetch_array($resultGetClaim)) {
  foreach($rowGetClaim as $k => $v{
    echo $v;
  }
}
```

OR

```
$names = array();
while($rowGetClaim = mysql_fetch_array($resultGetClaim)) {
  $names[] = $rowGetClaim;
}


foreach($names as $data){
  foreach($data as $k => $v) {
    echo $v;
  }
}
```

Comment: I am not sure to understand the last code. Why do you use two foreach, one for $names and one for $data? I just need to pass the array $names from the mySQL loop to the foreach and then the results should be related and consequential..Is that what the code you provided does?

Comment: `foreach ($data as $k=>$v)` splits out each row into name/value pairs such that `$data[$k]=$v` and for every value of `$k`.  It means you don't need to hard-code what you're expecting to see in the `$data` array (in terms of keys)

Comment: Well your question wasnt clear. The third example puts all of the rows retrived from the DB into an array in the while loop. Then in the foreach loop it goes over that array outputting all the values of the row. You woudl use this example if you had the mysql code in a serete file on in a completely separate part of the document from where you want to output.

Comment: The firs and second examples both out the data directly in place while youre actually looping over the result set. The only differrence is that example one outputs only 3 of the columns and explicity access them by associative key. The second example outputs all the columns on a record and does so using a loop.

Answer (score 2):

You are not retrieving an array with all returned records, you are retrieving an array which contains a single record.

To get the next `name` (the next record), you must make another call to mysql_fetch_array.

The code you present does that implicitly by assigning $rowGetClaim within a while conditional. A failed mysql_fetch_array call would return `false`, which would exit the while loop.

There is absolutely no need to use the for each as you presented. Just place the `echo` right after the assignment (e.g.

`$region = $rowGetClaim['region'];`

`echo $region`

Comment: No no no..That is simple I know that..I really need to know how to pass that in a foreach. I cannot explain the reason because I would need one hour in that case. I just need to know how to transform that $names in an array valid for the foreach and that EVERY result related to $name will be consecutive in the foreach, such as $city, $region etc...

Comment: `for each` works on arrays. `$name` isn't an array and DOES NOT CONTAIN EVERY RECORD. period. The `while` is your `for each` statement in all relevant respects.